# How do I get multi-bit ports to work in Yosys when the module is BLIF?

Tags: verilog, yosys

I cannot figure out how to get separate synthesis of modules to work in Yosys. Consider this simple two-module example:

**bottom.v**

```verilog
module bottom(x, out);
    input  [0:7] x;
    output [0:7] out;
    assign out = x+1;
endmodule
```

**top.v**

```verilog
module top(x, out);
   input  [0:7] x;
   output [0:7] out;
   bottom b(.x(x), .out(out));
endmodule
```

Now, synthesizing these together works as intended:

```
$ yosys -q -o top.blif -S top.v bottom.v
$
```

But if I first synthesize *bottom.blif* from *bottom.v*, I get an error message saying that there is no port *out* in the module *bottom*:

```
$ yosys -q -o bottom.blif -S bottom.v
$ yosys -q -o top.blif -S top.v bottom.blif
ERROR: Module `bottom' referenced in module `top' in cell `b' does not have a port named 'out'.
$
```

Why does this happen? Googling for issues, I have found references to the *hierarchy* command in contexts that I do not fully understand. I have tried running that command before *synth*, but it does not affect the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BLIF file format does not support multi-bit ports. This has nothing to do with Yosys, it is simply a limitation of the file format. Thus, when writing a design with multi-bit ports to a BLIF file, all ports are automatically split into single bit ports. So in the BLIF file there is no 8-bit wide port `out`, there are 8 single-bit ports `out[7]`, `out[6]`, `out[5]`, `out[4]`, `out[3]`, `out[2]`, `out[1]`, and `out[0]`.

So when you try to mix the Verilog and BLIF files like you have described, the `bottom` module does not match the interface of the `top.b` cell anymore.

---

Edit: I've now added `read_blif -wideports` in git commit [7e0b776](https://github.com/cliffordwolf/yosys/commit/7e0b776a793f648bed3338dfbc6b25bc1c24e873). This allows you to merge the individual single-bit ports again when reading a BLIF file back into Yosys. This way you can use BLIF as interchange format between Yosys and ABC without breaking module interfaces with multi-bit ports.